# How can I run a trigger in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I need syntax for it. What exactly happens in databases back end when triggers are executed?I also need a simple example on it.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx):

> A trigger is a special kind of stored procedure that automatically executes when an event occurs in the database server.

Here's the full syntax:

> -- SQL Server Syntax
>   Trigger on an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement to a table or view (DML Trigger)
>
> CREATE TRIGGER [ schema_name . ]trigger_name  ON { table | view }  [
>   WITH  [ ,...n ] ] { FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF }  {
>   [ INSERT ] [ , ] [ UPDATE ] [ , ] [ DELETE ] }  [ WITH APPEND ] [ NOT
>   FOR REPLICATION ]  AS { sql_statement  [ ; ] [ ,...n ] | EXTERNAL NAME
>    }
>
> ::=
>       [ ENCRYPTION ]
>       [ EXECUTE AS Clause ]
>
> ::=
>       assembly_name.class_name.method_name

And an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER reminder1
ON Sales.Customer
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS RAISERROR ('Notify Customer Relations', 16, 10);
GO
```